# Is pointer addition with an int variable different from addition with an int literal?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this snippet of code, trying to check if two arrays are equal:

```
int arr1[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int arr2[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};

int *p1 = arr1;
int *p2 = arr2;

if (end(arr1) - p1 == end(arr2) - p2) // Check if sizes are equal
{
    for (size_t i = 0;
         p1 != end(arr1);
         ++i){
             if (*(p1 + i) != *(p2 + i)){ // Check if each ith element is equal
                 cout << "Arrays not equal!" << endl;
                 return 0;
             }
         }
    cout << "Arrays equal!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else // Not equal if sizes don't match
{
    cout << "Arrays not equal!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I end up getting `"Arrays not equal!"`. So, I was looking into the `if` condition, when I noticed that `*(p1 + i)` for the first `i`, i.e., `i = 0`, seems to give a value of  `32766`, whereas if I write `*(p1 + 0)`, I'm getting the first element of `arr1` as expected. Why does this happen?

Comment: Your `for` loop never terminates, so you have undefined behavior when you read beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that! Thanks for that catch! However, I'm getting this issue in the very first iteration of the `for` loop, before the undefined behaviour begins.

Comment: If a program contains UB then the behavior of the entire program is undefined.

Comment: @TrainHeartnet No, you are not.

Comment: Whoa, you're right, I just modified the condition in the `for` loop to `(p1 + i) != end(arr1)` and the error disappears! But this is very weird to me as a beginner in C++; how does the compiler know UB is bound to happen, before it actually happens?

Comment: @super: Ah, you're right! I was printing the value inside the `if` condition, so it got printed only after the first fail (the first out-of-bound). Thanks so much for the help, @super @Oktalist!

Comment: It doesn't really "know". But it optimizes aggressively. An infinite loop with no observable side-effect is not allowed, so it can assume that `*(p1 + i) != *(p2 + i)` _must_ be true for some value of `i` because otherwise the `for` loop would run forever with no observable side-effect. So it can skip the `for` _and_ the `if` and go straight to the `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop condition is wrong, `p1` is never equal to `end(arr1)`, which is why `i` goes well beyond the array bounds.

```
int arr1[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int arr2[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int *p1 = arr1;
int *p2 = arr2;

if (std::end(arr1) - p1 == std::end(arr2) - p2) // Check if sizes are equal
{
    for (size_t i = 0;
         (p1 + i) != std::end(arr1); // (p1 + i) instead of p1 here
         ++i) {
        if (*(p1 + i) != *(p2 + i)) { // Check if each ith element is equal
            std::cout << "Arrays not equal!" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Arrays equal!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
} else // Not equal if sizes don't match
{
    std::cout << "Arrays not equal!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd figured it out right before you posted! :)